# How to get multiple vertices that match the condition in a single gremlin query

Tags: gremlin

New to gremlin and need help. I have a graph contains below vertices and relationship.

A ---hasLocation---> B <---uses--- C

Possible cases data stored in the graph are:

1) A --> B <-- C

2) A --> B

3) A

4) C

5) C <-- B

I would like to have a single gremlin query to ONLY return all vertices in above 1) which has the complete path and filter rest of the cases. The gremlin traversal must start from vertex A.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you well, you want:

```
g.V('A')                // Start from vertex A, assuming vertex id is 'A'
    .out('hasLocation') // Traverse in the outgoing direction from 'A' to the 'B' vertex
    .in('uses')         // Traverse in the ingoing direction from 'B' to the 'C' vertex
    .path()             // Display path
```